# How to open a file in Spyder

Tags: python

I don't know how to open a file from my desktop and use it in my Python program.

```
def c("New Text Document (2).TXT"):
    program = {}

    with open(New Text Document (2).TXT, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
```

What am I doing wrong? This is the beginning of the code. Thank you for your responses in advance.

Comment: If `"New Text Document (2).TXT"` is in your current directory first step is altering your function to know that is the file being opened. Something like: `def c(doc_location = "New Text Document (2).TXT")` and then `with open(doc_location, 'r') as file:` what you are doing is hard to understand as it is not valid syntax

Comment: @Student perfect glad you got the answers you needed! Ask away as needed, but please keep in mind that there are so many answers in SO that cover common questions while getting started. This question, although a bit specific your case, did have quite a few answers that are searchable that would have provided similar information. Best option is to try and find an answer on SO first, then if you can't find what you need post your code with as much detail as possible.

Comment: @ViaTech I've tried but I didn't understand from other questions. I'm a beginner, but thank you for your care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a string as parameter of the `c` function, you shall use a variable name for that:

```py
def c(fname):
    program = {}

    with open(fname, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()

c("New Text Document (2).TXT")
```